# Potential and potential energy

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy, conventions

I know when a negative charge moves in the direction of a uniform electric field its potential energy increases and its potential decreases. For example, its potential energy changes from $0.9\ \rm{mJ}$  to $1.2\ \rm{mJ}$, but its potential changes from $-90\ \rm V$ to $-120\ \rm V$. Where is the potential zero, and where is the potential energy zero?
Do they become zero at different locations?

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The **Electric potential** associated with a point is just **electric potential energy** *per charge* ("volt" is "Joules per coulomb". If one increases, the other would increase as well, and vice versa.

Comment: Usually in electrostatics you define the potential to be the potential energy per unit charge, so with this definition I don't think for a small test charge the potential and the potential energy can simultaneously change the way you describe. They must remain proportional.

Comment: @Steeven Maybe the OP is confused about if the charge is negative?

Comment: Yes. Charge is negative.

Comment: Related question: [How can a negative charge move towards a position of a higher electric potential but lose electric potential energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155186/how-can-a-negative-charge-move-towards-a-position-of-a-higher-electric-potential)

Comment: @Steeven Regarding your first comment, it is exactly the point I was trying  to make in my answer. Electrical potential energy and electrical potential increase or decrease together. The confusion is due to the arbitrary definition of "high" and "low" potential. A positively charged region is a region of high potential only if you consider the work required to move positive charge. But if you consider the work required to move negative charge, a negatively charged region is a region of high potential.

Comment: @AaronStevens See my comment to Steeven. I disagree with the diagram in the answer to your link. The positive charged plate is an area of low potential as far as negative charge is concerned.

Comment: @BobD Potential shouldn't depend on the charge you are looking at. Think about the relationship between force and field acting on a negative charge. We don't flip the sign of the field if the field is acting on a negative charge. We say the force acts opposite the field in that case.

Comment: @AaronStevens Sorry Aaron, but it takes external work to move negative charge towards a negatively charged plate and that increases both its potential energy and its potential.  When negative charge moves towards the positively charge plate it loses potential energy and potential.  It doesn't matter what you call the positive and negatively charged regions (high potential, low potential, red or blue) it doesn't alter that fact. That's the way I see it.

Comment: @BobD ok that's fine. Then you should also flip the sign of electric fields acting on a negative charge.

Comment: @AaronStevens I would agree with that. By current convention the direction of the field is taken as the direction of the force that a positive charge would experience if placed  in that field. The convention could just as well be the direction of the force that a negative charge would experience. That is of course the reverse. But convention aside, if external work is needed to move a charge, both its potential energy and potential increase. Thanks.

Comment: @BobD $$V_b-V_a=-\int\mathbf E\cdot \text d\mathbf l$$ Since negative charges, without external forces, tend to move in the opposite direction of the field, then this corresponds to an in increase in potential

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes, but again, that is based on the direction of the field being defined as away from positive charge, is it not?

Comment: @BobD Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96531/discussion-between-aaron-stevens-and-bob-d).

Comment: @BobD Yes, it's true for any field

Answer (score 1):

Electric potential is just the electric potential energy *per charge*. In other words, electric potential just depends on the charge distribution around you, where as if you were looking at a charge in the field caused by the charge distribution you could then say it has an associated potential energy in that configuration.

In light of this, the relation between electric potential energy $U$ and electric potential $V$ for a charge $q$ is just $$U=qV$$ Therefore, these two values need to be equal to $0$ at the same point in space. Of course, this $0$ point can be chosen to be at various locations, but once you set it then you have to stay consistent, and $U$ and $V$ will both be $0$ at that location.

Therefore your example is totally fine. If the potential energy goes from $0.9\ \rm{mJ}$ to $1.2\ \rm{mJ}$ and your potential goes from $-90\ \rm{V}$ to $-120\ \rm{V}$ nothing is wrong. In either case the values are moving farther away from $0$. If you moved the charge in the other direction back to where one value was $0$, you would find the other value to be $0$ as well.

Comment: Ok. Then my example is wrong? potential energys in two points are 0.9 and 1.2 and potentials related to two points are  90 and 70.This is wrong?

Comment: @user3728644 Do you mean because all of your numbers are positive?

Comment: Suppose potential from left to right decreses. Then potential become zero in right side. But potential energy encreases from left to right then potential energy must become zero in left side.

Comment: @user3728644 Your example is false because the potential and potential energy do not have the same ratios. You need to think of an example where the charge is kept constant

Comment: Are these numbers correct? 0. 9 and 1.2 for potential energy and minuse 90 and minuse 120 volt for potential.

Comment: In this situation potential must become negative. Correct?

Comment: @user3728644 Yes that all works out fine now

Comment: I saw those numbers in a question. Thank you.

Comment: @user3728644 Please upvote any useful answers and accept one answer as the correct answer for future readers.